# Installing Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to install the latest Beautiful Soup on Mac 10.11.3. Whenever I run `pip install beautifulsoup4` the terminal defaults to installing bs4 for python 2.7 not 3.5. How do I install Beautiful Soup for Python 3.5 not 2.7?

Comment: @wilbur Don't make trivial edits to closed posts. It will push them to reopen queue and add a burden to the reviewers. If the post is closed, allow the OP to edit. Regards

Comment: @BhargavRao ah of course, my mistake! I just looked at the answers and saw that people were having a hard time seeing the `pip install` line. I'll keep that in mind in the future, sorry to have inconvenienced y'all

Comment: @wilbur Not a problem when you do it for the first time. Good that you learned it early.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `python3` binary on your system

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: pretty sure this solved it

Comment: Good to know. You could also make a python3 virtualenv using the same `python3 -m` command. The "-m" means "module".

Comment: Did you install python 3.5 ? If not then download 3.5 then go to terminal of python 3.5 the  try to install it. Most probably you are on python 2.7 terminal.

Comment: @FarhanAhmed I would advise always using latest Python, specifically miniconda.